# Save rows independently as text files in r

Tags: r

I have a .csv file with a column containing different pieces of text in each row.
As an example:

> **Text**
>
> Love the way it looks. Ok for the price. I wish it had a front cover
>   as well.
>
> this is a great case. The color was true to the site and it is so sturdy.
>
> I ordered this case because I have a white Iphone 3G S and its a little scratched on the back

What I'm trying to code is a loop to save every single of these textual rows as an independent .txt file (using write.table, I guess).

In other words, if there are 1,000 rows with different text pieces, I would like to have 1,000 independent .txt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a mess but why not just:

```
inp <- readLines( file= ..filename.. )
setwd( ..path_to_dir..) 
for (i in seq(length(inp)){ cat( inp[i], file=paste0( i, ".txt") ) }
```